# Use textbox value on submit as a query string variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How would I take a text box value and use it in the query string on submit? I'd like it to start as this,

/News?favorites=True

and end up something like this after the user enters in a search and clicks search.

/News?query=test&favorites=True

The controller action looks like this

```
public ActionResult Index(string query,bool favorites)
{
   //search code   
}
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355547/getting-value-from-an-asp-net-mvc-textbox-on-submit-click) is something close to what I'd like to do, but I'd like to use the query string and maintain the existing values in the query string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. place the textbox inside a `<form>` with `method="GET"`
2. use javascript to read the value and pass it to the server (with AJAX or `window.location` to perform a redirect)

Example with a `<form>`:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("index", "news", FormMethod.Get)) { %>
    <label for="query">Query:</label>
    <%= Html.TextBox("query") %>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
<% } %>
```

Example with javascript:

```
<label for="query">Query:</label>
<%= Html.TextBox("query") %>
<%= Html.ActionLink("Search", "index", "news", new { id = "search" }) %>
```

and then in a separate js file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#search').click(function() {
        var query = $('#query').val();
        // Here you could use AJAX instead of window.location if you wish
        window.location = this.href + '?query=' + encodeURIComponent(query);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Using the form tag is what I was looking for but the problem is that it wipes out any existing query params. With this method if the url was /News?favorites=True and I submit with the search, and exception is thrown(missing bool param), and the favorites is lost.  Is there a way to keep the current params?

Comment: You could include the `favorites` parameter as hidden tag inside the form: `<%=Html.Hidden("favorites") %>`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Added  <input type="hidden" name="favorites" value="<%=Request.QueryString["favorites"]%>" /> to the form tag and I'm good.

Comment: I'm glad you included encodeURIComponent, that's something easy to overlook when you're just looking for a quick fix (I almost did).

Comment: what if i want to show the search result inside a div element? @DarinDimitrov

Answer (score 0):

Using Darin's above `<form>` answer but with Razor markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "news", FormMethod.Get)) 
{ 
<label for="query">Search:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("query")
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```